Add additional scheme in FastAPI docs (HTTP or HTTPS)
I am making some fastAPI routes which automatically generates the documentation, In documentation I want to add an option to select schemes (HTTP or HTTPS).
I tried adding CORS to the API:
app = FastAPI()

# Implement CORS
origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "https://example.com"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

But the schemes aren't showing up.
Also added custom config:
def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="My FastAPI App",
        version="1.0.0",
        description="This is a FastAPI app that supports HTTP and HTTPS",
        routes=app.routes,
    )
    # Add support for both HTTP and HTTPS schemes
    openapi_schema["schemes"] = ["http", "https"]
    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema


app.openapi = custom_openapi

but this also didn't work.
Expected result is to get this on the upper left of the docs:


Image is taken from SwaggerUI docs

How can I achieve this?

If you use OpenAPI 3.x, the HTTP(S) schemes are part of servers URL values: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/

Schemes is only available with swagger 2.0 (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/basic-structure/)
Now, with current version of FastAPI, it's using swagger 3.0 and it's using Servers (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/basic-structure/) for adding an option to select schemes.
def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title="Custom title",
        version="2.5.0",
        summary="This is a very custom OpenAPI schema",
        description="Here's a longer description of the custom **OpenAPI** schema",
        routes=app.routes,
    )
    openapi_schema["servers"] = [
        {
            "url": "http://api.example.com/v1",
            "description": "Main (production) server"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://staging-api.example.com",
            "description": "Internal staging server for testing"
        }
    ]
    openapi_schema["info"]["x-logo"] = {
        "url": "https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/img/logo-margin/logo-teal.png"
    }
    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema

Result:

